# Compatibility comparison types problem in application

Tags: powerapps

Please, help to solve the problem.

In form I created ComboBox. In dropdown of ComboBox I need to see the column from another table, filtered by another column.

I tried next code:

```
Filter(Choices('List of sites'.cr15c_SiteName); 
Value('CCCM agency status3') = "Active level 1")
```

Where:

List of sites - Name of the table, from what i took info
cr15c_SiteName - schema name of the column I want to display in the dropdown list
CCCM agency status3 - name of the filtered column
Active level 1 - Filtering option

In this code I get the error “Incompatible comparison types. It is impossible to compare these types: Control, OptionSetValue (CCCM agency status list)

Where CCCM agency status list - Entity, from what i take options for dropdown for CCCM agency status3 column

How can I solve the type compatibility comparison types problem and how can I edit the code

Tried different options of code, whitc founded in forums - nothing helped

Comment: Really difficult to follow - could you add better line breaks to your question please.
`Value(....)` converts a string to number and `"Active level 1"` is a string, so try without `Value(...)` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also tried without Value(...). I have the same mistake. only difference if "imposible to compare this tipes: Control, Text"

Answer (score 0):

Just re-read your question. `'CCCM agency status3'` is a drop down control - so you'll need to access its selected item value `'CCCM agency status3'.Selected.Text`

Comment: Just tried it. Writes the error "Invalid name. Cannot recognize "Selected."
I also now realized that here I should refer to a column of another table - maybe it makes sense to write like this: "'List of sites'.'CCCM agency status'". But in this case the error also appears that the specified column is not available

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was a DropDown control, is it a ComboBox control? And if yes, are multiple selections allowed?

Let's take a step back. Try without any filter - does this work? `Choices('List of sites'.cr15c_SiteName)`

Comment: Sorry if I didn't formulate this clearly. Yes, I have a ComboBox.
Let me try again to explain in more detail.
I have a table 'List of sites'.
It has columns:
Site Name - the data in this column is generated by a drop-down list, which is taken from the third table and CCCM agency status - the data is taken from Entity, which is called "CCCM agency status list".

Comment: In an application that fills out another table, I need to create a ComboBox that will display the Site Name column data, filtered by CCCM agency status.
Now according to what I get. If I simply enter Choices('List of sites'.cr15c_SiteName) in the ComboBox, there are no errors, but no data is displayed. Although, if I write a similar line in the gallery created for this, everything works

Comment: What line did you provide for the Gallery? And which property is displayed in the Gallery?

Comment: For the gallery I specified a line "Choices('List of sites'.cr15c_SiteName)". But I’ve already figured this out - choices already works in ComboBox, all I have to do is make a filter

Comment: Do you need help with the Filter part? `Filter(Choices('List of sites'.cr15c_SiteName); 'Property name' = "do a test string for now")`

Comment: Yes, with the filter part.
Last option which i tried is: Filter(Choices('List of sites'.'Site Name'); 'List of sites'.'CCCM agency status' = "Active level 1")
But in this case also added one more Mistake - "the specified column is not available in this context"

Comment: Do as my last comment just to test the Filter. It is hard to give specific help as I am in the dark. Once you have it working for a static known string, then you can look to replace that static string from a control.

Comment: I tried it and got the error "Invalid name. Can't recognize "Property name""

Comment: You need to change `'Property name'` to the actual property name. Ok.. select your ComboBox control, select Advanced in the right properties pane, third one down, what does it have for "DisplayFields" ?

Comment: It has one field - Site name

Comment: So now try `Filter(Choices('List of sites'.cr15c_SiteName); 'Site name' = "do a test string for now")`

Comment: Tried. There is no mistakes, but the dropdomn in ComboBox is empty

Comment: Have your replaced "do a test string for now" with a known string? Please provide your full expression.

Comment: When I entered an existing option - this option appeared in the ComboBox list.
full expression: Filter(Choices('List of sites'.'Site Name'); 'Site name' = "school_Beregova_NA")
In ComboBox is school_Beregova_NA

Comment: So your filter is now working, right? What's next?

Comment: With this field yes, thank you. But, as I said earlier, I need the filter to be based on a different field - CCCM agency status. But, if I specify it, the error "the specified column is not available in this context" appears.

Comment: What is `CCCM agency staus`? A control?

Comment: CCCM agency status  is another column in the table  'List of sites'  the data is taken from Entity, which is called "CCCM agency status list"

Comment: And will CCCM agency status have multiple values (rows) that you want to use in the filter?
Try *something* like: `Filter(Choices('List of sites'.cr15c_SiteName); 'Site name' in 'List of sites'.'CCCM agency status list')`

Comment: Yes. For example it could be "Active level 1". But I don't need to create a separate ComboBox to select the condition of CCCM agency status. This condition must be hardcoded in the filter like Filter(Choices('List of sites'.'Site Name'); 'CCCM agency status' = "Active level 1")" But it doesn't work

Comment: I'm confused, are you needing a filter with a condition that is also filtered?

Comment: Not certainly in that way. In the 'List of sites' table, the CCCM agency status column can have different values from the dropdown list, but I only need rows with the value "Active level 1"

Comment: Or, for starters, you can make the ComboBox display only those options that are already in the 'List of sites' table, and not the full list